# Difficulty managing access to Document using Profiles and the Metadata API

Tags: metadata-api, profile, ant, document, package.xml

We are having trouble managing the permissions associated with `Document` via the Metadata API.

We are using `ant` to both deploy and retrieve the metadata files.

In order to deploy successfully we can:

Add the following xml to a `.profile` file.

```
<objectPermissions>
    <allowCreate>true</allowCreate>
    <allowDelete>true</allowDelete>
    <allowEdit>true</allowEdit>
    <allowRead>true</allowRead>
    <modifyAllRecords>true</modifyAllRecords>
    <object>Document</object>
    <viewAllRecords>true</viewAllRecords>
</objectPermissions>
```

Ensure `Document` is **not** in the CustomObject section of the `package.xml`

This updates the permissions on the profile correctly.

**However, this change is not included in the `.profile` file when we do a retrieve.**

**In order to retrieve successfully we can add the `Document` element to the `CustomObjects` section of the `package.xml`**

On doing so we get the warning:

```
package.xml - Can't retrieve non-customizable CustomObject named: Document
```

And the retrieve does not bring down a definition for the `Document` object.

This would be fine, but if we include the `Document` node in the `package.xml` and do not include a definition for that object then future deploys we get:

```
package.xml (Document) -- Error: An object 'Document' of type CustomObject was named in package.xml, but was not found in zipped directory
```

The whole deployment then fails.

**Is anyone aware of a single configuration in the `package.xml` that will result is successful deployments and retrievals of the `Document` permissions in profiles?**